# JavaScript charts and graphs

Tags: javascript, charts

I am tasked with building an HTML/JavaScript application which is not networked (it runs on a PC as part of a Windows application).

Is there a library which will create simple graphs and charts in 100% HTML and JavaScript as a client application?

Comment: Please refer these link [http://webdesignledger.com/resources/13-useful-javascript-solutions-for-charts-and-graphs](http://webdesignledger.com/resources/13-useful-javascript-solutions-for-charts-and-graphs) http://www.developertutorials.com/scripts/7/134/ http://www.liquidx.net/canvasgraphjs/

Comment: Take a look at [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into flot (a plugin for the jQuery library): http://code.google.com/p/flot

Answer (score 1):

Try

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/

http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ex/